# Scheme function that return composition of functions

Tags: function, scheme, r5rs

How to realize a function that takes as input an any number of procedures with one argument and returns another function is the composition of these procedures in Scheme.

For example:

```
(define (f x) (* x 2))
(define (g x) (* x 3))
(define (h x) (- x))

((comp-func f g h) 1) => -6
((comp-func f g) 1)   => 6
((comp-func h) 1)     => -1
((comp-func) 1)       => 1
```

Comment: Which order is the composition supposed to be happening? E.g., in your first example with `(comp-func f g h)`, are you computing `(f (g (h 1)))` or `(h (g (f 1)))`?  They'd both work out to -6, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clean solution would be

```
(define (comp-func . procs)
  (define (comp-rec arg procs)
    (if (null? procs)
        arg
        ((car procs) (comp-rec arg (cdr procs)))))

  comp-rec)
```

However with this solution you need to call it like this `((comp-func f g h) 1 (list f g h))`.

Here is a solution that will work if you call it like in your examples, however it is a bit uglier because we need to use `set!` to change `procs` argument.

```
(define (comp-func . procs)
  (define (comp-rec arg)
    (if (null? procs)
        arg
        (let ((proc (car procs))
              (rest (cdr procs)))
          (set! procs rest)
          (proc (comp-rec arg)))))

  comp-rec)
```

Answer (score 7):

As written, the question is ambiguous, because we can't tell in which order you're composing the functions.  That is, we can't tell whether
**((comp-func f g h) 1)** computes **(f (g (h 1)))** or **(h (g (f 1)))**, since both would work out to **-6** in this case.

That said, this problem can be solved by a (left to right) *fold* a.k.a. *reduction*; once you know how to compose *two* functions, you can *reduce* that binary composition over a *list* of functions.

First, composing two functions is easy:

```
(define (compose2 f g)
  ;; Returns a function that computes (g (f x)).
  (lambda (x)
    (g (f x))))
```

Now, to reduce (a.k.a. fold left to right) a function `f` over a list `(x1 x2 ... xn)` with an initial value `i` means computing

```
(f ... (f (f (f i x1) x2) x3 ...) xn)
```

(by definition). Composing a list of functions `(f1 f2 f3 f4)` is then just *folding* the **compose2** function with an initial value that is the identity function.

```
(define (identity x)
  x)

(define (compose . functions)
  (reduce compose2 identity functions))
```

`reduce` is a built-in function that does the (left to right) folding.

I'll use some functions where the order matters, so that we can see the difference in results:

```
(define (f x) (* x x))
(define (g x) (+ x 3))

(display ((compose f g) 3))
;=> 12 == (g (f 3)) == (3^2)+3

(display ((compose g f) 3))
;=> 36 == (f (g 3)) == (3+3)^2
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32783677/9713831)'s nice recursive solution, I would like to add that there's no need to use `set!`. Inside `comp-func` you can simply return a lambda function that calls `comp-rec` with the list of procedures as the extra argument.

```
(define (comp-func . procs)
  (define (comp-rec arg procs)
    (if (null? procs)
        arg
        ((car procs) (comp-rec arg (cdr procs)))))
  (lambda (arg) (comp-rec arg procs )))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for any intermediate define or let or set or what ever.

We stay pure functional and need no variables.

```
(define (comp-func . procs)
  (lambda (arg)
    (if (null? procs)
      arg
      ((car procs) ((apply comp-func (cdr procs)) arg)))))
```